# Как сделать фон элемента прозрачным?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, веб-дизайн, css

Как сделать так, чтобы фон у элемента был прозрачным, а содержимое отображалось так же, как и без блока.

```
<div class="page">
<div class="block">
<p> Text </p>
</div> <!-- end block -->
</div> <!-- end page -->
```

Задавая вот так css, я получаю абсолютно другой цвет:

```
div.page {
width:450px; height:300px;
    background-color:#123456;
    border:3px solid #555555}
div.block {width:260px; height:140px; margin-top:79px; margin-left:94px; background-color:#ffffff; border:1px solid #333333;
/* Internet Explorer */
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
/* CSS3 standard */
opacity:0.5}
div.block p {margin:47px 0 0 10px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/10tf97c3/

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/color

Comment: Спасибо, @soledar10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Копайте в сторону значения **rgba** для свойства **background**

Comment: Я понимаю и знаю, разницы нет, все равно текст в абзаце тоже становится прозрачным, а мне это не надо.

Comment: @shilgen, при задании свойства background:rgba(0,0,0,.5) текст не должен становиться полупрозрачным. Вы что-то не то делаете.